# Value in Formula Bar not shown correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in Excel that contains the following values :

[image]

However, when I click on the cell that contains '**01**' for example, the formula bar shows '**1**'.
[image]

Is there any way to have '**01**' displayed in the formula bar instead of '**1**'?

Comment: Format your column as Text.

Comment: Likely situation: Your column contains bare numbers, the column is *formatted* to DISPLAY those with two digits. (`CTRL`+`1`, Custom / User defined `00`). The only way is to select and copy the numbers, set the cells to text mode, then paste as text

Comment: The same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644789/excel-show-leading-zero-in-formula-bar